# SQL Server columns as rows in result of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, querying

How to get table where some columns are queried and behaves as rows?

**Source table**

```
ID | Name | Funct    | Phone1 | Phone2 | Phone3
1  | John | boss     | 112233 | 114455 | 117788
2  | Jane | manager  | NULL   | NULL   | 221111
3  | Tony | merchant | 441100 | 442222 | NULL
```

**Wanted result**

```
ID | Name | Funct    | Phone  | Ord
1  | John | boss     | 112233 | 1
1  | John | boss     | 114455 | 2
1  | John | boss     | 117788 | 3
2  | Jane | manager  | 221111 | 3
3  | Tony | merchant | 441100 | 1
3  | Tony | merchant | 442222 | 2
```

`Ord` is a column where is the order number (`Phone1...Phone3`) of the original column

**EDITED:**

OK, `UNION` would be fine when phone numbers are in separed columns, but what if the source is following (all numbers in one column)?:

```
ID | Name | Funct    | Phones
1  | John | boss     | 112233,114455,117788
2  | Jane | manager  | 221111
3  | Tony | merchant | 441100,442222
```

Here I understand, that column `Ord` is a non-sense (so ignore it in this case), but how to split numbers to separed rows?

Comment: If you know that you have 3 phones for each customer than UNION ALL is a good option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `union all`:

```
select id, name, funct, phone1 as phone, 1 as ord
from source
where phone1 is not null
union all
select id, name, funct, phone2 as phone, 2 as ord
from source
where phone2 is not null
union all
select id, name, funct, phone3 as phone, 3 as ord
from source
where phone3 is not null;
```

You can write this with a `cross apply` as:

```
select so.*
from source s cross apply
     (select s.id, s.name, s.funct, s.phone1 as phone, 1 as ord union all
      select s.id, s.name, s.funct, s.phone2 as phone, 2 as ord union all
      select s.id, s.name, s.funct, s.phone3 as phone, 3 as ord
     ) so
where phone is not null;
```

There are also methods using `unpivot` and `cross join`/`case`.

Comment: OK, and is there another one solution to do that? With _cross aplly_ or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer below,

```
Declare @table table
(ID int, Name varchar(100),Funct varchar(100),Phones varchar(400))

Insert into @table Values 
(1,'John','boss','112233,114455,117788'),
(2,'Jane','manager','221111' ),
(3,'Tony','merchant','441100,442222')

Select * from @table
```

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
Declare @tableDest table
([ID] int, [name] varchar(100),[Phones] varchar(400))

Declare @max_len int,
        @count int = 1

Set @max_len =  (Select max(Len(Phones) - len(Replace(Phones,',','')) + 1)
                From    @table)

While @count <= @max_len
begin
    Insert  into @tableDest
    Select  id,Name,
            SUBSTRING(Phones,1,charindex(',',Phones)-1)
    from    @table
    Where   charindex(',',Phones) > 0
    union   
    Select  id,Name,Phones
    from    @table
    Where   charindex(',',Phones) = 0

    Delete from @table
    Where   charindex(',',Phones) = 0

    Update  @table
    Set     Phones =  SUBSTRING(Phones,charindex(',',Phones)+1,len(Phones))
    Where   charindex(',',Phones) > 0

    Set     @count = @count + 1
End
------------------------------------------
Select  * 
from    @tableDest
Order By ID
------------------------------------------
```

Final Result:

[image]

Comment: very nice Jithin, thanx for useful code, but I have asked for using it into a query (select, view...). How to use it inside a query? Using UDF...or...is there another way how to write the loop into a select without inserting to a variable table?

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT CONCAT(
      'CREATE TABLE New_Table (',GROUP_CONCAT(
                            DISTINCT CONCAT(Name, ' VARCHAR(50)')
                            SEPARATOR ','),');')
      FROM
      Previous_Table
      INTO @sql;
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
```

This query generates a row in a table from the column values of another table. This may help you